# Disjoint Union – Is meaningful to write $A \subseteq A \sqcup B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, convention

I have a very basic question concerning [**disjoint union**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointUnion.html):

> Given two arbitrary sets $A$, and $B$, is meaningful to write $A \subseteq A \sqcup B$?

Intuitively, I would say it does not, because the objects in $A$ are different from the objects in $A \sqcup B$.

*[The point is that the elements of $A \sqcup B$ look like $(x, i)$, for an arbitrary $x \in A \cup B$, and an arbitrary index $i$ that can take two values.]*

Thus, I am wondering:

1. If I am correct;
2. If the mathematical convention is different from my intuition (which is correct), and people actually write 
   $A \subseteq A \sqcup B$ even if it is not completely correct.
   *(I actually found such a statement in a book, and it left me puzzled).*

Looking forward to any feedback.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Writing $A\subseteq A \sqcup B$ is an abuse of notation and I *personally* would not say it is "good abuse".

The intended meaning is something along the lines of:

> There is a canonical monomorphism $\operatorname{copr}_1 : A \to A \sqcup B, a\mapsto (a,0)$

so you can view $A$ as being "embedded" into $A\sqcup B$. But the map $\operatorname{copr}_1$ really is necessary to specify *how* it is embedded.

PS: $\operatorname{copr}$ stands for "coprojection". Some people call this thing an "injection"; I am not a fan of that because (e.g.) it is not just any old injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see! Btw, may I ask you something: disjoint union look like something that you don't find in books easily (I found in one book about topology). Where do you find it usually?

Comment: @Kolmin Any introduction to category theory. This is also known as a *coproduct*. Other than that I don't really know.

Comment: Ok, right! Because you don't actually find it in set theory books, at least not in what I read.

Comment: One last comment/question. Is it possible that the convention really comes from topology? What I mean is that, to topologize $A \sqcup B$, in order to be really precise from a notational standpoint, we would need a page or so just to start to talk about the issue. On the contrary, with this convention, we just say that $G \in \tau_{A \sqcup B}$ if $G \cap A \in \tau_A$, and $G \cap B \in \tau_B$ (which is not correct at all, but still is understandable by the reader, and is quick - even if the reader has to be careful). Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It can help for a first exposure to the topic, though it is not really formal mathematics.

Comment: My main concern with abuse of notation is, that it *can* become a huge hindrance when you try generalize something.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Thanks a lot again!